# Why aren't iTunes Store links opening from Chrome and Edge?

Tags: windows, ios-appstore, google-chrome, itunes-store, links

I'm trying to open iTunes links from the web in Windows 10.

Whenever I click on a "View in iTunes" link in Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome, I get sent to a page saying I should download and install iTunes. I already did that and I'm on a fresh install of Windows. I've restarted after a repair install of iTunes without any difference.

If I do the same in Internet Explorer, the links work and iTunes opens fine.

Are others experiencing this at all?

I'm using 64-bit Chrome as I did on Windows 8.1. I don't remember having this problem on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with Apple's website assuming you don't have iTunes installed, when it should really just try and open it anyway.

You can fix this in Chrome by spoofing your user agent to Chrome for OS X, or any other OS X browser.

I've been using [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg) to do this. Once you've installed it, go to its options and add a new user agent for Chrome on OS X. The one in particular I'm using is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36
```

Once you've added that to the list of user agents, you can go to "Permanent Spoof List" on the left side panel in the options, and add a new rule for apple.com using the user agent you just added.

This will make the Apple website think you're running OS X, causing iTunes URLs to correctly open.

Answer (score 1):

Simply to install the extension [iTunes links fixer for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itunes-links-fixer/cbieldhkddeceogkmdmpfnfcfhamfggk)

Comment: Actually in step 7. you should click F12, choose console and paste `its.detect.itunesDetected=function(){return true;}` into it, later confirming by enter.